# Difference of time between server and database in Grails 4.0.3

Tags: date, grails, time

I developed a Grails 4.0.3 Rest API to send notifications the to users of a system.

When I save a message in the database, I don't know why but it adds three hours from the current Date. First of all I thought that it was the hour of te server, but when I saw it, I noticed the hour of the server is correct.

Now in Brazil the time is 2022-08-16 12:08:54.710 and the server is correct. But in the database, it saves 2022-08-16 14:55:54.710.

The code below saves a message:

```
def message = new Message(userId: springSecurityService?.principal?.id,
                                        author: jsonObject.get('author'),
                                        partId: params.partId,
                                        title: jsonObject.get('title'),
                                        text: jsonObject.get('text'),
                                        createdOn: new Date()).save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
```

Could anyone help me with this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: What database are you using, and what time zone is it configured to?

Comment: Hi Daniel, I am using MS SQL Server, but I think that the problem is not there, because when I run the application locally it works as expected. In the server the hour is correct, but when I depoly the app, it adds 3 hours to what it ould be the correct hour.

Comment: [root@DMZAPL03 ~]# timedatectl                                                                         Local time: Thu 2022-08-18 10:04:43 -03                                                      
 Universal time: Thu 2022-08-18 13:04:43 UTC        RTC time: Thu 2022-08-18 13:04:42       Time zone: America/Sao_Paulo (-03, -0300)     NTP enabled: yes
NTP synchronized: yes
RTC in local TZ: no      DST active: n/a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem this way in BootStrap.groovy

```
System.setProperty("user.timezone", "GMT-03")
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Sao_Paulo"))
```